# Update package.json version in Bazel rule

Tags: package.json, bazel

I'm trying to create a Bazel rule that will update the version number in `package.json` before packing with `npm_package`.

In short I want to take `packages/server/package.tpl.json` and create an output `package.json` that I can depend on in `npm_package`.

I've tried a bunch of different was that include error such as `read-only file system`, `no such attribute 'out' in 'stamp_package_json' rule` and `rule 'package_json' has file 'package.json' as both an input and an output` and the current error `The following files have no generating action: packages/server/package.json`

My project structure looks like:

```
/
  /packages
    /server
      /src
        BUILD.blaze
      BUILD.blaze
      package.tpl.json
  /tools
    /npm
      BUILD.blaze
      stamp_package_json.bzl
```

This is a monorepo so it has more packages then just server.

In `packages/server/BUILD.blaze` I use two rules:

```
package(default_visibility=["//visibility:public"])
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "npm_package")
load("//tools/npm:stamp_package_json.bzl", "stamp_package_json")

stamp_package_json(
    name = "package_json",
    package_json = "package.tpl.json",
    out = "package.json"
    )

npm_package(
    name = "red-server_package",
    deps = [
        ":package_json",
        "//packages/server/src:shared-red-server-library"
    ],
    replacements = {"//packages/": "//"},
)
```

If I rename `package.tpl.json` to `package.json` and just include that file in `npm_package` it works as expected, except that the version is incorrect.

The `stamp_package_json` rule is defined in `tools/npm/stamp_package_json.bzl`:

```
def _impl(ctx):
    package_json = ctx.file.package_json

    # The command may only access files declared in inputs.
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        inputs = [package_json],
        outputs = [ctx.outputs.executable],
        arguments=[package_json.path],
        progress_message = "Stamping package.json file %s" % package_json.short_path,
        command="jq '.version=\"123\"' $1 > $@")

stamp_package_json = rule(
    implementation=_impl,
    executable = True,
    attrs = {
        "package_json" : attr.label(allow_single_file=True),
        "out": attr.output(mandatory = True)
    }
)
```

As mentioned above it currently throws an error:

`The following files have no generating action: packages/server/package.json`

I can't seem to figure out how to deal with this. Or if my approach is any good. Or if this can be achieved in any other way.

**edit**: Wrote a blog post about the solution I ended up with: https://medium.com/red-flag/developer-diary-day-1-bazel-build-system-with-monorepo-and-typescript-6f7a5a0a2b00

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [blog post mentioned in the question](https://medium.com/red-flag/developer-diary-day-1-bazel-build-system-with-monorepo-and-typescript-6f7a5a0a2b00), the work of transforming `package.tpl.json` to `package.json` can be done with a genrule

```
genrule(
    name = "package_json",
    srcs = ["package.tpl.json"],
    outs = ["package.json"],
    cmd = "jq --arg version $$(cat $(GENDIR)/../../volatile-status.txt | sed -nE 's/^BUILD_SCM_VERSION v([0-9.]+).*$$/\\1/p') '.version=$$version' <$< > $@",
    stamp = True
)

npm_package(
    name = "shared-red-server-library_package",
    deps = [
        ":package_json",
        ":shared-red-server-library"
    ],
    replacements = {"//shared_red_node_library/packages/server/": "//"},
)
```

This looks like a good solution, except it brings external dependency on unix tools `jq` and `sed`, so build fails if either is missing or if the environment has some weird incompatible version of it.